# Taking div tag content and applying it to inline style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a super novice to javascript, and maybe this has been answered elsewhere but I can't find it because I'm still learning the terminology.

I'm trying to use the content of a div tag to define the css values of a div it is nested within.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function data(){
                 alert();
                 var sizeOverride = document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML
alert(sizeOverride)
             }
         </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div id=sizeChange>
         <div id="newdata">
             40 <!--The idea is for this to be 40px-->
         </div>
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("sizeChange").style.fontSize = "sizeOverride" + "px";
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eventually the plan is to use this to define the location and label of a bar on a graph, i.e. there will be in a page that utilizes hotfields to fill in the information in the div. That framework is already built, but the goal is to use that data to define the css values of that div.

There aren't any errors but nothing is happening. It's probably something simple. I appreciate you bearing with me.

Comment: `sizeOverride` is a variable, but you're concatenating `"sizeOverride"` as a string near the bottom, rather than a variable. Don't wrap quotation marks around variable names.

Comment: Add the javascript in the head to into the script-tag at the bottom. At the time of the head-tag execution the DOM will not be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function data(){
                  return parseFloat(document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML.trim());
             }
         </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div id=sizeChange>
         <div id="newdata">
             40
         </div>
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">

      document.getElementById("sizeChange").style.fontSize = data() + "px";
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: notice the below changes
1. the element "newdata" must have just the value (number). Without which, document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML will contain everything that is in "newdata" including the comments.
2. notice the parseFloat in data function. This is used to be able to convert the innerHTML which is string to a number.

Comment: I would use:`parseFloat(document.getElementById('newdata').innerText.trim());` just to take care of unsuspicious characters.

Comment: added! totally makes sense :-)

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks folks. That saves me a lot of time in trial and error.

Comment: Here's the rub. Can this defined value override a css style with a "position:absolute" property?

Comment: nope. the above line of code sets font size, while you are setting position: absolute